# Swift: how to make NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource() not return nil for the first check?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsbundle

I'm checking if a video exists with the following code:

```
if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4") != nil
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

The filename is video.mp4, and it's in my project. (Imported as folder group, and copy items if needed unchecked).

The first time I click the button that check the code above it returns nil. The second time I click it returns the correct value.

I'm using xCode 7.3.1 with Swift.

Btw, if I double check like the code below, it still only works the second time I click the button.

```
    if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4") != nil
    {
    }
    if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4") != nil
    {
            //do stuff
    }
```

How can I make sure the first check doesn't return nil?

I've checked this on an actual ipad and with the simulator. Both ios9.

The code is inside a function which is in my main ViewController class. The function is called by a button which is also in this class.

Thank you!

Comment: where is this code at? show more about how it's called and what other code is around it. is this on a device / simulator?

Comment: Your "double check" code makes no sense to me. If the first call returned `nil` then the second would not be executed at all ...

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I edited my original post. Martin R: Sorry I changed the code to make more sense, the new code is what I actually tried BTW.

Comment: The code provided does not seem to be enough to determine the error, as I cannot replicate your error. Can you add all the code for the button?